# Django not sending Server Error (500) emails

Tags: python, django

I have a Django website hosted on a remote server. Whenever I encounter a `Server Error (500)` I am supposed to get an email with more information about the error. I am not getting these emails.

`send_mail()` works on this server through the shell.
`mail_admins()` works on this server through the shell.
Triggering a `Server Error (500)` only displays the error on the page and no email is ever sent.

Here are what I believe to be the relevant settings for sending email as well as receiving error emails.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

SERVER_EMAIL = 'me@gmail.com'

ADMINS = [
        ('me', 'me@gmail.com'),
]
```

Comment: How are you handling the error and triggering the mail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue.

The problem was that I was not restarting Gunicorn (and maybe Nginx) after making changes to settings.py. I restarted Gunicorn with the proper email settings in settings.py and now everything works.

Comment: The simplest of solutions often catches us out!